# phonegap plugin to check gps is on or off

Tags: cordova, gps, phonegap-plugins

I have been trying to find out a plugin which will trigger if the gps is turned on or off during the app is running. So I start the app and the gps is turned off but later I turn it on.

I have tried

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

and

```
cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

but they don't put a sort of binding. In the start I can look if it is on or off but as the app is running I can't

Comment: Check out this plugin - https://github.com/fastrde/cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps  which lets you check gps status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) provides [registerLocationStateChangeHandler()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#registerlocationstatechangehandler) which allows you to register a callback function to be invoked when a change in Location state occurs - I believe this should satisfy your requirement of "a plugin which will trigger if the gps is turned on or off during the app is running":

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

then

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler(function(state){
    if((device.platform === "Android" && state !== cordova.plugins.diagnostic.locationMode.LOCATION_OFF)
        || (device.platform === "iOS) && ( state === cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED
            || state === cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED_WHEN_IN_USE
    ))){
        console.log("Location is available");
    }
});
```

Comment: We also use this if GPS is on but single is week or gps is lost?